# How to format datetime in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am trying to port MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')` to MsSQL equivalent by using `CONVERT()`.
How to format equivalent datetime string in SQL SERVER 2012 to give this output `'2014-05-24 01:24:37 AM'`?

Comment: Reopened as SQL Server 2012 has `format` function not in 2008.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and up you can use [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt')
```

In prior versions, you might need to concatenate two or more different datetime conversions to get what you need, for example:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 23) + ' ' + 
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 22), 11)), 11);
```

See the Date and Time Styles section of [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for all of the built-in formatting styles.

---

I would keep in mind that unless you have a good reason for it, I mean a *really* good reason, formatting is usually a better job for the technology displaying the data.