# Need to show date in specific format sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show current date in following format.
9/16/2019 5:35:55 PM

select getdate()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format datetime in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837672/how-to-format-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: SQL Server's date and time data type don't have a format. if you need it in a format, then that's for your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format()`

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Date datetime =GETDATE()
select FORMAT(@Date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt') AS CurrentDate
```

OR

```
Select Convert(char(10), getdate(),101) + Right(Convert(VarChar(20),getdate(),100),8)
```

You can use this Query...